# Django ORM update on QuerySet object

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset like.

```
message = Message.objects.select_related('user').get(id=1)
message_user = message.user
```

When i use .save() function on message_user it works.

```
message_user.first_name = 'ABC'
message_user.save()
```

When i use .update() function it does't.

```
message_user.update(first_name='ABC')
```

`'User' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: use `save(update_fields=[])` if you want only specific fields to be written to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update()` is a method in the `QuerySet` class, but not in the `Model` class that your `Message` model inherits from.

Pre-Django 1.5 you can do `Message.objects.filter(id=1).update(first_name='ABC')` for a single row update, or `Message.objects.filter(...).update(first_name='ABC')` if you need bulk updates

You can also call it on the `Manager` of a model, e.g. `Message.objects.update(first_name='ABC')` to update all rows

Since Django 1.5 you can also specify which fields are to be saved in a single object update with:

```
message_user.first_name = 'ABC'
message_user.save(update_fields=["first_name"])
```